# Memory leaks on using $rootScope.$on and $scope.$on in the controller

Tags: angularjs

I have `LoadingIndicatorCtrl` where I put two listeners on `$rootScope` and two on just `$scope`. When call some function, scope listeners get destroyed and something funny happens with `$rootScope` listeners:

```
{
    $$listeners: [f, null, null, null, null]
}
```

Is it okay if I have listeners array full of `null`'s?

**info**

I'm using angularjs 1.2.5

Listeners are picked into array and then looped through in order to be unsubscribed:

```
var indicatorListeners = [
          $scope.$on('show', show),
          $scope.$on('hide', hide),
          $rootScope.$on('showLoadingIndicator', showLoadingIndicator),
          $rootScope.$on('hideLoadingIndicator', hideLoadingIndicator),
];
```

Comment: when u open modal window at that time first hide the loading indicator then show new loading indicator

Comment: I tried to bind the boolean prop of the window on `<loading ng-if="showWindow"></loading>`. It works for the window, but stops working when I surfing around the "Body".